# "is of paramount importance" or "is a paramount importance"

Tags: articles

> It is **of / a** paramount importance to integrate retinopathy services into the existing child and newborn services

using "of or a", In the above sentence, which one i should use

Is it "of" OR article "a"

Comment: We say things are 'of importance'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That is suspiciously similar to an answer.

Comment: To post an answer to a low-quality question is deplored and can attract downvotes.

Comment: I was born with ROP (retinopathy of prematurity), so I agree wholeheartedly with the sentiment being expressed.

Answer (score 2):

"Of importance" is the idiomatic usage, so also "of paramount importance" is the correct usage.

We think of *importance* as an uncountable noun, so there are not different "importances." As such, there isn't "an importance," either.

Similar usages of *of* are *of note*, *of interest* and *of distinction*.

Answer (score 0):

In short, "of paramount importance" is the answer, which means "super duper important".

A common grammar pattern is being used here, that is, `be of + noun/noun phrase`.

More info at [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/240944/109190).